# Нет перевода у диалога "Что не так с комментарием"

Tags: дефект, локализация, комментарии, тревоги

Не нашел уже заведенную на эту проблему <strike>багу</strike>.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Перевод обновится в ближайшее время.

Comment: Хмм...https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7870/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%83%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b-%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85#